# sinon.spy(func) is not producing a called even when it is called

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon, sinon-chai

I have a test that is spying on a stubbed out method. The method is faking a dependency. I can verify the method is actually being called. I can even verify that it's being called with the expected arguments. However, the spy isn't providing a `true` when looking at `called` or `calledWith`.

It's the `mailerStub` method that is proxying the `mailer` dependency.

I've even placed a `console.log` for the `spy.displayName` and it's `mailer` as expected.

What did I do wrong here?

```
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var sinon = require('sinon');
var mockReq = require('./../mockReq');
var mockRes = require('./../mockRes');
var utils = require('./../utils');
var config = require('./../../server-config');

var mailerErr;
var mailerTemplate;
var mailerStub = function mailer(to, subject, html, callback) {
  callback(mailerErr);
};

var emailTemplatesErr;
var templateErr;
var templateHtml;
var emailTemplatesStub = function emailTemplates(root, callback) {
  callback(emailTemplatesErr, function template(name, locals, callback) {
    callback(templateErr, templateHtml);
  })
};

var sut = proxyquire('./../../middleware/sendEmail', {
  '../mailer': mailerStub,
  'email-templates': emailTemplatesStub
});

describe('middleware/sendEmail', function sendEmailSpec() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    mailerErr = false;
    mailerTemplate = undefined;

    emailTemplatesErr = false;
    templateErr = false;
    templateHtml = undefined;
  });

  it('should send an email', function(done) {
    var req = new mockReq();
    var res = new mockRes(next);

    res.email = {
      templateName: 'template-name',
      to: 'test@test.com',
      subject: 'some subject',
      locals: {
        firstName: 'test'
      }
    };

    templateHtml = 'HTML';

    var spy = sinon.spy(mailerStub);
    sut(req, res, next);

    function next(msg) {
      console.log(spy.displayName);

      expect(msg).to.be.false;
      expect(spy.called).to.be.true;
      //expect(spy.calledWith(res.email.to, res.email.subject, templateHtml)).to.be.true;

      done();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to help somebody in the future, I figured out the problem. The stub needs to be setup with the function and then the stub needs injected into the `proxyquire` configuration.

This is likely because it's not an `object.func` that I'm watching but rather an existing function.

```
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var sinon = require('sinon');
var mockReq = require('./../mockReq');
var mockRes = require('./../mockRes');
var utils = require('./../utils');
var config = require('./../../server-config');

var mailerErr;
var mailerTemplate;
function mailerStub(to, subject, html, callback) {
  callback(mailerErr);
}
var mailerStubSpy = sinon.spy(mailerStub);

var emailTemplatesErr;
var templateErr;
var templateHtml;
var emailTemplatesStub = function emailTemplates(root, callback) {
  callback(emailTemplatesErr, function template(name, locals, callback) {
    callback(templateErr, templateHtml);
  })
};

var sut = proxyquire('./../../middleware/sendEmail', {
  '../mailer': mailerStubSpy,
  'email-templates': emailTemplatesStub
});

describe('middleware/sendEmail', function sendEmailSpec() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    mailerErr = false;
    mailerTemplate = undefined;

    emailTemplatesErr = false;
    templateErr = false;
    templateHtml = undefined;
  });

  it('should send an email', function(done) {
    var req = new mockReq();
    var res = new mockRes(next);

    res.email = {
      templateName: 'template-name',
      to: 'test@test.com',
      subject: 'some subject',
      locals: {
        firstName: 'test'
      }
    };

    templateHtml = 'HTML';

    sut(req, res, next);

    function next(msg) {
      expect(msg).to.be.false;
      expect(mailerStubSpy.called).to.be.true;
      //expect(spy.calledWith(res.email.to, res.email.subject, templateHtml)).to.be.true;

      done();
    }
  });
});
```